# Method call ends with error ORA-04063 + ORA-06512

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have such objects and methods:

```
create or replace type PolicyType as object(
policy_id number,
policy_nr varchar2(20),
price number) NOT FINAL;
/
create or replace type TravelerType as object(
first_name varchar2(30),
last_name varchar2(30),
pers_code varchar2(12));
/
create or replace type TravelersType as table of TravelerType;
/
create or replace type ref_TargetPlaceType as object (
target_code varchar2(4),
description varchar2(30));
/
create or replace type TravelPolicyType under PolicyType ( 
target_code REF ref_TargetPlaceType,
traveler_data TravelersType,
MEMBER FUNCTION getTraveler (p_code IN varchar2) RETURN TravelerType,
MEMBER PROCEDURE addTraveler( traveler IN TravelerType ));
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY TravelPolicyType  AS
MEMBER FUNCTION getTraveler(p_code IN varchar2) RETURN TravelerType AS
  BEGIN
  for i in 1 .. self.traveler_data.count() loop
  if( self.traveler_data(i).pers_code = p_code )
  then
  return self.traveler_data(i);
  end if;
  end loop;
END;
MEMBER PROCEDURE addTraveler(traveler IN TravelerType) AS
BEGIN
 self.traveler_data.extend();
 self.traveler_data(self.traveler_data.count) :=traveler;
END;
END;
```

I am tying to call methods, bet getting error for both
ORA-04063: type body "SQL_LPZCXWDSKRAXJUEWPMXNUMWYH.TRAVELPOLICYTYPE" has errors ORA-06512:

```
declare 
    policy_d TravelPolicyType;
    traveler TravelerType;
  
begin  
    select value(a) into policy_d from travel_policies a where a.policy_nr='TP00000000003';
    traveler:=policy_d.getTraveler('050976-12568');
end;


declare 
    policy_d TravelPolicyType;
    new_traveler TravelerType;
    
begin  
   select value(a) into policy_d from travel_policies a where a.policy_nr='TP00000000003';
   new_traveler:=TravelerType('Test','Traveler', '123456-44444');
   policy_d.addTraveler(new_traveler);
end;
```

Can not understand what I am doing wrongly. Please help with advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See what errors are reported in that object:

```
select * from user_errors;
```

| NAME | TYPE | SEQUENCE | LINE | POSITION | TEXT | ATTRIBUTE | MESSAGE_NUMBER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TRAVELPOLICYTYPE | TYPE BODY | 1 | 4 | 22 | PLS-00302: component 'TRAVELERS_DATA' must be declared | ERROR | 302 |
| TRAVELPOLICYTYPE | TYPE BODY | 2 | 4 | 3 | PL/SQL: Statement ignored | ERROR | 0 |

Your type has `traveler_data`, but the body refers to `travelers_data`. You need to make that naming consistent.

Comment: Yes, thanks, i fixed that, but still same error

Comment: With select * from user_errors; i found other error and issue fixed, call works, thank you very much :)